# How to use ATECC608 chip to generate JWT signatures in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, microchip, esp-idf

Where can I find an example written in ESP IDF on how to authenticate to Google IOT Core using JWT generated by Microchip ATECC608?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you checked out the [ATECC608 example in IDF](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/peripherals/secure_element/atecc608_ecdsa)? It also points to some [tutorial for external connections](https://github.com/espressif/esp-cryptoauthlib/blob/master/esp_cryptoauth_utility/README.md#using-atecc608a-with-esp32-wroom-32)

Comment: I was able to generate the private and public key. The private key is stored on Slot1 and public on slot 11. I am using atcab_get_pubkey() to return the public key. How do I transfrom from X and Y integers in big-endian format. 64 bytes to base64 string so I can put it on Google IOT cloud? I tried to use atcab_base64encode() but it's inserting weird characters and my public key is invalid on google iot core: Generated public key is: {X:c888157854773773e93b18c34803d417d6d2b3e54f40b451fe0eb8a1ae824feb, Y:8dfb0ab2aca0eca0c296e1579cfbaa58aba2cd8e223c76d43a01197a33ab6d93} .

Answer (score 1):

The ESP-IDF (IoT Development Framework) is the SDK for Espressif chips. You need to install dependencies for the ESP-IDF, install the ESP-IDF itself, set up the ESP32 device, and then connect it to IoT Core.

Considering your microchip is integrated with ESP32, This [Google Community](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/embedded-c-getting-started) tutorial  helps in authenticating your ESP32 with cloud iot.

- Install and configure ESP-IDF
- Set up the ESP32 device
- Set up your device registry by installing cloud SDK and then generating elliptic curve (EC) device credentials for authenticating the device
- Create Pub/Sub topic and subscription to be used for storing telemetry

  ```
    gcloud pubsub topics create topic-name
    gcloud pubsub subscriptions create data --topic=topic-name
  ```
- Create device registry and add your device to registry
- Connect ESP32 device to IoT Core

  - The mqtt_task function sets up the parameters needed to connect to the cloud. It uses the private key created in iotc_connect_private_key_data.
  - To connect your ESP32 to Cloud IoT Core, use iotc_connect, which is from the IoT Core Embedded C SDK
  - This part of the program will generate jwt

  ```
   char jwt[IOTC_JWT_SIZE] = {0};
   size_t bytes_written = 0;
   iotc_state_t state = iotc_create_iotcore_jwt( CONFIG_GIOT_PROJECT_ID, 3600, &iotc_connect_private_key_data, jwt, IOTC_JWT_SIZE, &bytes_written);

   if (IOTC_STATE_OK != state) {
   printf("iotc_create_iotcore_jwt returned with error: %ul", state); 
   vTaskDelete(NULL);
   }
  ```

Full code is available [here](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/embedded-c-getting-started).

Comment: I was able to generate the private and public key. The private key is stored on Slot1 and public on slot 11. I am using atcab_get_pubkey() to return the public key. How do I transfrom from X and Y integers in big-endian format. 64 bytes to base64 string so I can put it on Google IOT cloud? I tried to use atcab_base64encode() but it's inserting weird characters and my public key is invalid on google iot core: Generated public key is: {X:c888157854773773e93b18c34803d417d6d2b3e54f40b451fe0eb8a1ae824feb, Y:8dfb0ab2aca0eca0c296e1579cfbaa58aba2cd8e223c76d43a01197a33ab6d93}

Comment: Hi @Larinni Malheiros, please avoid sharing public/private keys in the public forum. Moreover, this is a new question which does not relate to the original question asked. So, I would suggest opening a new thread for the same.